# Can I send a function and one parameter in a map()?

Tags: javascript

I am looping a cursor using map(). While I'm looping I want to call a function that use the the first parameter of the map.

```js
workflow.map(workflow, total(workflow))
```

Is it possible?

Comment: It should be, but it would be called like this I believe: `workflow.map(workflow, total(workflow()))`

Comment: Can you post the definition of `workflow` and `total` functions?

Comment: `workflow = ['dev', 'hq', 'mkt'];

total('dev') {this.mykitWorkflow(wflow).map ( (tool)=> { 
   return totalWorkflow = totalWorkflow + Number(tool.price)  ;
  })}`

Comment: I have 3 workflows and each one has 2-5 tools each. Each tool has a price. So I want to find out how much do I have to pay for each workflow.